# Converting Negative integer number into positive using if_abs

Tags: python

After prompting a user to enter an integer and printing the absolute value of it, how do you convert a negative input integer into positive using if statements.

Comment: `number *= -1 `

Comment: You can do this by writing `if number < 0: number *= -1` but that is the wrong way to do it. The correct way is just `number = abs(number)`.

Answer (score 0):

`number` is your integer input.

Code:

```
number = abs(number)
```

Comment: why even check `if number < 0`?

Comment: Ohh, really. `if` not needed here. Thanks, @hiroprotagonist